# When is Newton's Method guaranteed to converge to a good solution (non-linear system)?

Tags: numerical-methods

My knowledge of Newton's Method is partial. I am trying to understand what guarantees this method can give on the solution of systems of non-linear equations.

Specifically, I have a set of non-linear equations that are easily twice differentiable. What additional conditions do I need to fulfill in order to guarantee that Newton's Method finds a good solution? How important is the starting point? if it is important, how can I guarantee that I find a good starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items below should help you to look up further details of Newton's Method for system of nonlinear equations.

**Advantages:**

- Q-quadratically convergent from good starting guesses if the Jacobian $J(x_*)$ is nonsingular
- Exact solution in one iteration for an affine $F$ (exact at each iteration for any finite component functions of $F$)

**Disadvantages:**

- Not globally convergent for many problems
- Requires $J(x_k)$ at each iteration
- Each iteration requires the solution of a system of linear equations that may be singular or ill-conditioned

**References:**

- See [*Section 3*](http://cims.nyu.edu/~donev/Teaching/NMI-Fall2010/Lecture6.handout.pdf)
- This has a worked [*example*](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~jove/courses/mam208/nonlinsyst.pdf)

**Notes**

- For Newton's method, you would choose a tolerance and use some vector norm to test that the result is good enough.
- If you choose a bad starting value, all bets are off.
- You might also want to look into quasi-Newton methods.
- For good starting values, you want to look into the Steepest Descent method, which is used to find accurate starting approximations for the Newton-based techniques.
- As an aside, you probably also want to look at and understand "Constrained" versus "Unconstrained" methods.

Comment: Nice summary! This is really a nice resource.

Comment: Agreed, so bored I am actually looking a series solution method for a DEQ (yuck!) :-)

Comment: Thanks! One point which is still not clear to me is how do I know if I reached the global solution for a specific problem, if I can tell that a starting point was good only in retrospect? For what classes of problems is global convergence guaranteed (convergence rate is less important to me)?

Comment: @Bitwise: For Newton's method, you would choose a tolerance and use some vector norm to test that it is good enough. If you choose a bad starting value, all bets are off. You might also want to look into quasi-Newton methods. For good starting values, you want to look into Steepest Descent method, which is used to find accurate starting approximations for the Newton-based techniques.

Comment: @Bitwise Unless your problem is quasi-convex, all bets are off. There is no general method to tell whether a local minimum that you find is also a global minimum. You may be able to prove global optimality for some problems using branch and bound techniques.