# When is Newton's Method guarenteed to converge

Tags: numerical-methods

From what I understand, for Newton's Method to converge in the equation

$$g(x_n) = x_{n-1} - \frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}$$

(1) $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ must be continuous around the root.

(2) The initial guess must fall within this interval.

(3) The condition $|g'(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$ in the interval around the root must be true.

This answer [Showing that Newton's method converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/660142/308260) confirms my idea.  I also found [When is Newton's Method guaranteed to converge to a good solution (non-linear system)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/371015/308260) which has a good explanation of Newton's Method, but not really what I was looking for.

I just need to know if the above mentioned conditions guarantee convergence?

Comment: 1) What is the interval you designate in (2) as "this interval" ?   2) No, these conditions are not necessary neither sufficient.

Comment: "The interval" is the interval around the root where $|g'(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie So these conditions do not guarantee convergence?  Are there conditions that do guarantee convergence?

Comment: There are. But in general there is nothing that you can check a priori.

Comment: There are such conditions as treated in the following paper you can fiind on the web vberinde.ubm.ro/.../ANUOC-1995-Berinde.PDF Usually they are very restrictive...

Comment: The problem of determining where Newton's method converges can be truly difficult and even chaotically behaved, as illustrated in the paper "On the iteration of a rational function: computer experiments with Newton's method" by Curry, Garnett, and Sullivan.

Comment: I found this answer on this site: [Sufficient conditions for the convergence of Newton's Method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/946762/308260) which is very similar to the conditions above.